# How can I efficiently display tabular data (medical patient vitals) in an Android app?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app, in which one of the functions will be to display patient vitals:

```
Timestamp|Heart Rate|SPO2|Resp./minute|ETC02|Systolic|Diastolic|Temp1|Temp2
```

Right now, I am displaying the information in a table:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9">
        <!--
            programmatically insert the table rows
        -->
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I make a database query for the vitals, stick the vitals in a List<>, then loop through the list to build table rows, which I insert into the TableLayout structure which I have obtained by using the findViewById method

```
TableLayout vitalsTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.vitals_table);
```

This method works, although it feels very kludgy

```
for(Vital vital : listOfVitals){
    int rowID = vitals.getId();

    TableRow newTableRow = new TableRow(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams dataRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    newTableRow.setLayoutParams(dataRowParams);

    TextView timeTextView = new TextView(context);
    timeTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
    timeTextView.setText(vital.getTime());
    newTableRow.addView(timeTextView);
    newTableRow.setId(rowID);

    // The same for all 9 vitals

    vitalsTable.addView(newTableRow);
}
```

Like I said, it works but it feels very kludgy, and it is slow. I really need it to display in a table, which is why I went this route.

I am VERY new at Android development (former JSP developer), so I thought I would check to see if there is a better, more elegant solution I should be using.

**EDIT:**
Here is what my data looks like from the SQLite query. I store the data in List<Vital>:

```
12:00:01,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:02,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:03,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:04,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:05,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:06,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:07,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:08,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:09,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
12:00:10,60,98,37,52,94,84,98.6,98.4
and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GridView:**

Grid View is good approach for showing this kind of data.
[Here you find basic tutorial for Grid View.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you, I will check out the tutorial. Will this be able to keep my columns aligned like a table?

Comment: Any idea how I would use this with my SQLite query return of List<Vital>? The example you posted uses images, but I need it for text data. Each line in my query return is a full set of data. I have added an example of my data in my original post.

Comment: Have look here -> http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/gridview/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 1):

if you have large data to display into screen in tabular format 
then go for Landscape mode and use GridView instead of TableLayout.

Comment: Will this be able to keep my columns aligned like a table?

Comment: Yes you can align, and it will reuse the views so that it will be memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

GridViews are probably your best bet in displaying the data in a table form.

To make the code feel less clunky you could make your own GridView object that takes in your patient data

```
public myGridView extends GridView {
    public myGridView(Vital v) {
        // Add each vital to your gridView
    }

    public addPatient(Vital v) {
        // Add another row of vitals to your gridView
    }
    // Any other needed methods
}
```

This would at least remove "clunkyness" from your code!

I do this with a gridview and a custom object that contains a TextView and an ImageView to display a good amount of data to users, and it seems to be quick and responsive.

GridViews are essentially the same as you are imagining as a table where they are all aligned in columns, the tricky part is going to be getting all of the layout settings correct to have everything display nicely even when the screens are different sizes :^)

Android's GridView examples in their documentation is really good in my opinion!
[Android - GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)